# Where do I put Microsoft.Scripting.Debugging so that our embedded interpreter can find it?

Tags: .net, ironpython, pdb, pdb-files

I am trying to debug a function I've written, and it is not possible to run it in the regular IronPython interpreter because of all the jiggery pokery we do when we start up the one we've embedded in our application.

However when I try and run the debugger:

```
import pdb
pdb.runcall(myFunction)
```

I get this message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Scripting.Debugging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Where do I put the DLL so that the embedded interpreter can use it? at the moment I have it in the same folder as the IronPython Libarary.

```
application folder
    resources folder
        IronPython folder
            DLL here
            Libs folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Having it next to IronPython.dll to in the DLLs folder should work. If not, you can always do a manual `Assembly.Load` to bring it in ahead of time, or `clr.AddReferenceFromFileAndPath` in Python.